# SVG as pseudo background image in React Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, material-ui

I use the React Material UI with JSS. I have the following structure:

```
<footer>
  <div className={classes.ContainerWrapper}>
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <div>
        <div className={classes.Text}>Text</div>
      </div>
      <Box marginLeft={6} className={classes.ButtonContainer}>
        <Button className={classes.Button} variant="contained">
          <Link to={...}>Link text</Link>
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The problem is that I want an SVG absolutely positioned compared to ContainerWrapper, partly **behind** the Container. My trials till now were:

- Using z-index (did not work because of the absolute position)
- Using negative z-index (did not work because the whole footer cannot have negative z-index, it has clickable elements)
- Putting SVG in the :after pseudo element as a background image.

When I tried the last one, I run into the following obstacles:

- This import throws an error:
  `import image from '../../assets/images/image.svg';` It works perfectly with png, btw.
- Finally, I tried to use inline SVG as follows:
  `` backgroundImage: `url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg...")` ``

The after pseudo part appears in the DOM in the proper size. However, I cannot see the image.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Considering the further plans, I need to find a way to use svg-s as a background image in material-ui.